# Informatica Flat File into Flat File gives Quotes

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a basic informatica load. Flat file to Flat file and no transformations.

My source flat file does not have quotes. 
EX: A B C D

When I run my job I get quotes.
EX: "A" "B" "C" "D"

Please help!

Comment: Just use ReplaceStr(Column,'"','') in an expression

Comment: REPLACESTR(1,Column,'"','') I tried in an expression transformation without luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the session, target file properties, you can set your preferences regarding double quote, single quote or no quote.

[image]

Comment: I double click the session, under Mappings, I click on my target (flat file) and do not see any options for that.

Comment: There should be a link called "Set file properties"

Comment: @JohnGali Not in `Mapping Designer`, check the option in session task under `Work flow manager`

Answer (score 0):

Set Optional Quotes to none in session, target file properties
     Set File Properties
           Delimited -> Advanced 
                  Set Optional Quotes to None
[image]